# Convert string to Unicode hex representation and back in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to convert a string into a string which contains all characters of the given string in their Unicode hex notation and back again. Target language is C++.

For example, given the German word `Hände`, I want to be able to convert this string into it's Unicode hex notation `U+0068 U+00E4 U+006E U+0064 U+0065`, and from it back to its original representation `Hände`.

How can this be accomplished in C++?

Comment: "all characters of the given string in their Unicode hex notation" ... "`HU+00E4nde`" ... So, `H`, `n`, `d`, and `e` are not characters?

Comment: This isn't any kind of standard format I know of, so you'll have to define it better. How is the `+` character encoded? What about characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (won't fit in four digits). Generally you would be better off reusing a standard encoding scheme that has existing compliant libraries you can use, for example JSON string literal encoding or UTF-8-URL-encoding.

Comment: @bobince It's a frequently used format in documentation, when speaking about Unicode characters (where the character is used as a space delimited word).  And the convention is four or more hex characters after the +.  I've never heard of it being used as a transmission format, however.

Comment: I think its a splendid idea. You should do that.

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment, what stop you to use this simple conversation?

```
std::u16string in = u"Hände";
stringstream out;

for (auto x : in)
    out << hex << "U+" << x << " ";

cout << out.str();
```

Output:

```
U+48 U+e4 U+6e U+64 U+65
```

Comment: +1 But he's using a UTF-8 encoded string so shouldn't `std::string` suffice?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Unfortunately no. He needs something more than `std::string` to hold `ä` character. Look at [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=86bc23921e95e842db40eff01a030d18-7904cf83bb2b27db3f32fade22b567cc)

Comment: Your code example is empty. :( So you're saying that the `u8` prefix won't work to store `ä`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Yes it can. The problem is when we want iterate over it to convert it to a hex, the output is `U+00H U+00� U+00� U+00n U+00d U+00e`.

Comment: @MM. How about `std::string in = u8"Hände";`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: No difference. I don't know why online compilers don't work right now!